# write a 2d shape file with NetTopologySuite

Tags: c#, shapefile, nettopologysuite

I created a routine that writes correctly shape files, but I have a problem: the shape is a 3d, but I need to write a 2d shape file.
  How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 9):

Noone give answer on Internet and I spent 2 days to finally find this solution :

```
using NetTopologySuite.Features;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using NetTopologySuite.IO;
using ProjNet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public static void TestCreate2Dshape(string shapeFileName)
        {
            int srid = 4326;
            var sequenceFactory = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Implementation.DotSpatialAffineCoordinateSequenceFactory(Ordinates.XY);
            var geomFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(PrecisionModels.Floating), srid, sequenceFactory);

            // use shapefilewriter to force geometryType a u want ex=point
            var tmpFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
            ShapefileWriter shpWriter = new ShapefileWriter(geomFactory, tmpFile,ShapeGeometryType.Point);

            // use the dataWriter to write the shape file with geometry and data
            ShapefileDataWriter dataWriter = new ShapefileDataWriter(shapeFileName, geomFactory);                 

            // create an entity and add to the features
            List<Feature> features = new List<Feature>();
            AttributesTable att = new AttributesTable();
            att.Add("ID", 1);
            var geomZ = geomFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(0,0)) ;

            // force geomz to geom xy using the shpWriter
            var geom = shpWriter.Factory.CreateGeometry(geomZ);

            // add to the features
            features.Add(new Feature(geom, att));

            // header
            DbaseFileHeader outDbaseHeader = new DbaseFileHeader();
            outDbaseHeader.AddColumn("ID", 'N', 10, 0);
            outDbaseHeader = ShapefileDataWriter.GetHeader(outDbaseHeader.Fields, Math.Max(features.Count, 1));
            dataWriter.Header = outDbaseHeader;

            // write the shapefile
            dataWriter.Write(features);

            // Create the projection file if necessary, choose value matching srid  
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(shapeFileName+".prj"))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84.WKT);
            }

            // delete the temporary writer
            shpWriter.Close();
            System.IO.File.Delete(tmpFile + ".shp");
            System.IO.File.Delete(tmpFile + ".shx");
        }
```

Comment: I just want to thank you very much! Saved me lots of headache. For me the missing piece of the puzzle was:
shpWriter.Factory.CreateGeometry(geomZ);